# Problematic flag window location on mobile

Tags: bug

Using Chrome on an LG G3, the location of the flag window in the Triage review queue appears to be off. When I hit flag, rather than it appearing at the top overlaid on the question, it appears on the bottom. This is undesired in my mind because it's hard enough to navigate on mobile SO without the dialogs bouncing around. Below shows the top of the form, and then again where the flag window appears when the button is pressed.

Can we get this looked into?
[image: Is this desired?]
[image: Bottom of the form]

Comment: What browser are you using? If on mobile, why not use the mobile theme - which is optimised for... mobile?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is how it appears on Chrome for Android. Switching between desktop and mobile doesn't change how it appears.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, coming from me, but how exactly are you flagging stuff from the triage review queue? AFAIK, there is no "flag" link.

Comment: @Oded Hitting Unsalvagable opens the flag window.